# What's the best way in writing to emphasize the pronunciation "wise-er" for the word "wiser"?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling

Suppose I want to write the sentence

"He may not be wise, but he is surely wise-*er* than he used to be"

with the spelling "wise-*er*" meant to indicate that the word "wiser" is to be pronounced so as to emphasize its second syllable (in order to highlight the difference between the two words).

Is the quoted sentence above the best way to indicate this?

My goals are a) for this intention to be clear and b) to find a way to write this that is as simple as possible.

Comment: Any solution is likely to be non-standard; I don't think any style guide or usage guide has rules for this. But your solution with italics looks fine for writing fiction or non-serious reportage (journalism other than the New York Times). In a comic book you might just write WISER with the ER in larger, bolder capitals.

Comment: It might be better to write "*more* wise". Italicizing "more" will express the emphasis.

Comment: Sorry. English has no accepted expression for that, nor anything like it.

If both your editor and your publisher will let you, choose the style they recommend… and please also recognise that will be their choice, not any kind of standard.

Can you cite other writers who've used special punctuation in situations like that?